# Очередной вопрос по тестированию: разделяемый юнит-тест

Tags: юнит-тесты, php

Предположим, есть некий сложный интерфейс, который реализуют несколько классов с разной "подложкой", но внешне они должны работать абсолютно идентично (пример - строковые данные, в основе которых лежит некий stream), другими словами, тесты для них должны различаться только создаваемым инстансом (в чуть более сложной версии - тесты совпадают, скажем, на 90%). Как корректно написать разделяемый тест для нескольких классов? Наследование, кмк, плохая идея, возможно, надо просто вынести сами тесты в отдельный класс (как StepObject в веб-тесте), которые будут выглядеть как `SharedTestClass::testDataRetrieval(StreamDataInterface $object)`, но тоже не очень нравится - сами тесты разделяются, но их вызов остается в основном классе, который все равно придется обновлять. Создавать тест-класс, который будет принимать в конструкторе FQCN класса совсем не вариант, потому что придется запускать его вручную, а это выдернет его из текущей инфраструктуры.

**Обновление**

Представим такую ситуацию

```
interface StreamBasedStringInterface {
    (static) public function substr((int) $start, (int) $length);
    (int) public function getSize();
}
class FileStreamString implements StreamBasedStringInterface { ... }
class MemoryStreamString implements StreamBasedStringInterface { ... }
```

У этих классов разная реализация, но абсолютно идентичный вывод, поэтому хочется написать один тест, который будет использоваться и обновляться для обоих классов разом. Остальной текст сверху - это предположения об использовании разных вариантов.

Comment: Честно, толком ни че не понял )) Чувство такое, что вы хотели про [DI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) спросить

Comment: @BOPOH, Обновил вопрос.

Comment: К DI, конечно, это имеет нулевое отношение

Comment: Вам наверное нужна вот такая [схема][1]

[1]:http://stackoverflow.com/a/3121883

Comment: @ua6xh, я ее описал чуть выше

> Создавать тест-класс, который будет принимать в конструкторе FQCN класса совсем не вариант, потому что придется запускать его вручную, а это выдернет его из текущей инфраструктуры.

Строго говоря, ручной вызов там необязателен, но тогда нужно внедрение автозагрузки и нарушение структуры тестов. Я, в принципе, стараюсь поддерживать FQCN в проекте, но Codeception вообще на них наплевать, поэтому это практически автоматическое внедрение свежего геморроя, придется следить за соблюдением FQCN в критических местах. Хотя по-хорошему именно так и должно быть.

Comment: @Etki Можно, конечно, и наследованием, но для себя я решил воспользоваться типажами (трейтами). [Пример библиотеки по работе с кэшем (Memcached, Redis, Couchbase,...)](https://github.com/romeOz/rock/blob/master/tests/core/cache/RedisTest.php#L14), [хендлеры для сессий](https://github.com/romeOz/rock/blob/master/tests/core/session/MemorySessionTest.php#L15) или посмотрите, как [реализованы тесты для различных РСУБД в Yii2](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/tests/unit/framework/db/ActiveRecordTest.php#L24).
И никто в этом случае не мешает воспользоваться полиморфизмом.

Comment: > Можно конечно и наследованием, но для себя я решил воспользоваться типажами(трейтами)

Та библиотека пока заглохла, но я попробую. Вообще хочется иметь полную поддержку 5.3, но codeception ее уже наверное запорол.

> посмотрите, как реализованы тесты для различных РСУБД в Yii2

Как [цензура]. Они тестируют active record в связке с реальной бд через класс-посредник. Так делают только те, кто раньше мозолил глаза своей версткой татьянычу. На уровне AR уже не должно быть никаких подробностей о нижележащей БД.